# Как передавать в часть пути HTTP запроса значение содержащее `/`?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Используем ASP.NET 6. Есть контролер, где в путь подставляются значения `docNumber` и `hash`:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v2/")]
public class GuaranteeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("file/{docNumber}/{hash}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(
        [Required()] IFormFile formFile,
        [FromRoute, Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] string docNumber,
        [FromRoute, Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)] string hash)
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

Далее для docNumber пытаемся передать значение `ББ-0007010/2022`. Кодируем это значение с помощью `Uri.EscapeDataString:

```cs
Uri.EscapeDataString("ББ-0007010/2022") // вернёт "%D0%91%D0%91-0007010%2F2022"
```

Получаем Uri

```
https://localhost:5000/file/%D0%91%D0%91-0007010%2F2022/4ead1aaf295f25e8f7deff0eecce085
```

А далее возникает проблема в методе `AddFile`. При вызове этого метода аргументу `docNumber` задаётся значение `ББ-0007010%2F2022`. Т.е. символ `/` не декодируется.

Как этого избежать? Т.е. как сделать так, чтобы символ %2F также декодировался в '/'?

Comment: Но зачем изобретать себе проблемы на ровном месте?

Comment: Проблема взята на сопровождение. Но ведь можно сказать, что идёт большой Хайп, типа никаких аргументов в Query, Путь чётко определяет ресурс? Всё хорошо до момента, когда пользователь начинает использовать спец символы.

Comment: Любопытно. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71114862/5045688 - Символ `%2F` в пути действительно не декодируется. Здесь - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2686 - в обсуждении опасаются возможных проблем с load balancers, reverse proxies etc. Так что лучше не передавать слэш в пути.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вот интересно, в этом случае https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71114862 есть решение. `[HttpGet("string/{**value}")]`. Добавление `**` позволяет получать декодированный символ `/`. Но это возможно только для последнего аргумента. В моём случае это не поможет.